# Country/state/city depedent select with json & jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a cascade dropdowns for country state and city. I want to also populate the city dropdown, so far country and state are ok, what am i missing? 
This is what i got so far:

```
<form id="dropdowns" action="index.html">

        <label>Country:</label>
            <select id="country" name="country">
                <option value="000">-Select Country-</option>
            </select>

        <br />

        <label>State:</label>
            <select id="state" name="network">
                <option value="000">-Select State-</option>
            </select>

        <br />

        <label>City:</label>
            <select id="model" name="model">
                <option value="000">-Select City-</option>
            </select>

        <br />

</form>
```

This is what i'm using for test purposes:

```
var myJson = {
"country": [
    {
        "name": "United States",
        "id": "usa",
        "states": [
            {
                "name": "State 1 USA",
                "id": "usaState1",
                "cities": [
                    {
                        "name": "City 1",
                        "id": "usaState1City1",
                        "area": "12345 sqkm"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "City 2",
                        "id": "usaState1City2",
                        "area": "12345 sqkm"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "State 2 USA",
                "id": "usaState2",
                "cities": [
                    {
                        "name": "City 3",
                        "id": "usaState2City3",
                        "area": "12345 sqkm"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "City 4",
                        "id": "usaState2City4",
                        "area": "12345 sqkm"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Australia",
        "id": "aus",
        "states": [
            {
                "name": "State 1 Australia",
                "id": "ausState1",
                "cities": [
                    {
                        "name": "City 5",
                        "id": "ausState1City5",
                        "area": "12345 sqkm"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "City 6",
                        "id": "ausState1City6",
                        "area": "12345 sqkm"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "State 2 Australia",
                "id": "ausState2",
                "cities": [
                    {
                        "name": "City 7",
                        "id": "ausState2City7",
                        "area": "12345 sqkm"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "City 8",
                        "id": "ausState2City8",
                        "area": "12345 sqkm"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

And this is the jquery script:

```
$.each(myJson.country, function (index, value) {
$("#country").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
});

$('#country').on('change', function(){
console.log($(this).val());
for(var i = 0; i < myJson.country.length; i++)
{
  if(myJson.country[i].id == $(this).val())
  {
     $('#state').html('<option value="000">-Select State-</option>');
     $.each(myJson.country[i].states, function (index, value) {
        $("#state").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
    });
  }
}
});
```

I can't get it work:

```
$('#state').on('change', function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
  for(var i = 0; i < myJson.country.length; i++)
  {
    if(myJson.country[i].states.id == $(this).val())

    {
      //console.log(myJson.country[i].states.id);
       $('#model').html('<option value="000">Cities</option>');
       $.each(myJson.country[i].states.cities, function (index, value) {
          $("#model").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
      });
    }
  }
 });
```

Comment: Where's your `$('#state').on('change'` function?

Comment: yes, where is state change event ?

Comment: updated, what i got so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need another nested loop in your `change` function for `state`. You are referencing `myJson.country[i].states.id`. But `myJson.country[i].states` is an array. It doesn't have an `id` attribute. You will need to loop through that array and find all cities with a matching state `id`. I would recomment flattening your object into a list of cities with an associated state `id`; Try something like this:

```
function getCities() {
    var cities = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < myJson.country.length; i++) {
      var country = myJson.country[i];
      for(var j = 0; j < country.states.length; j++) {
          var state = country.states[j];
          for (var k = 0; k < state.cities.length; k++) {
            var city = state.cities[k];
            cities.push({
                stateId: state.id,
                stateName: state.name,
                cityId: city.id,
                cityName: city.name
            });
          }
      }
    }
    return cities;
}
```

And then use this in your `state` `change` event:

```
  $('#state').on('change', function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
    var cities = getCities();
    $('#model').html('<option value="000">-Select State-</option>');
    var stateId = $(this).val();
    $.each(cities, function (index, value) {
      if (value.stateId == stateId) {
        $("#model").append('<option value="'+value.cityId +'">'+value.cityName+'</option>');
      }
    });
  });
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/40916zn4/7/

Comment: It's not working ok. it shows all the cities, not the ones for the selected country -> state.

Comment: My mistake. I combined your logic with mine in the `change` handler. I should have used one or the other. Check out the updated post with updated jsFiddle link.

Comment: @MattSpinks - possible to reactivate your JsFiddle again ?  The working snippet will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have a little modification in the original code. I have added another for loop in my code.

```
$('#state').on('change', function(){
      console.log($(this).val());
      for(var i = 0; i < myJson.country.length; i++)
        {
            for(var j = 0; j < myJson.country[i].states.length; j++) {

                if(myJson.country[i].states[j].id == $(this).val())

                {
                   $('#model').html('<option value="000">Cities</option>');
                   $.each(myJson.country[i].states[j].cities, function (index, value) {
                      $("#model").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
                    });
                }
            }
        }
     });
```